# How to utilize yum to only download RHEL 6 32bit patches?

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

How to utilize yum to only download RHEL 6 32bit patches?
I tried editing the yum.conf file and I have no luck in getting it download only 32bit patches.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to download *updates* (not patches) for the i686 architecture, you may want to run this command:

```
yum update *i686
```

[How to update only 64 bit packages ? - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/676183)

Comment: Silly of me to miss that. I am new and haven't utilized wildcards as I should. Thank you. 
Question: Doesn't some RHEL 6 updates have the i686 and i586 suffixes? I read previous version did, but I am unsure.